# A multiple of the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose that $f:V\to V$ is a linear transformation such that $f$ is represented by the same matrix with respect to every bases for $V$ (i.e., If $\lbrace e_i \rbrace$ and $\lbrace \bar{e_i}  \rbrace$ are different bases for $V$, then the matrices representing $f$ with respect to these different bases are the same). Does this imply that $f:V\to V$ must be a multiple of the identity transformation ?!

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $f$ is represented by $A$ with respect to the basis $\beta = (e_1,\dots,e_n)$ then it is represented by $P^{-1}AP$ with respect to the basis $\overline{\beta} = (\overline{e}_1,\dots,\overline{e}_n)$ where $P$ is a change of basis matrix. By assumption, you have $A = P^{-1}AP$ for all invertible $P$ which means that $AP = PA$ for all invertible $P$. Use this equality with various $P$'s to deduce that $A = cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: for all invertible $P$ or for some $P$? The change of basis matrix is unique .

Comment: @HusseinEid: The change of basis matrix is unique but your assumption says that we can choose any $\overline{\beta}$ and the resulting matrix will be the same. So each $\overline{\beta}$ will give us a unique invertible $P$ (and also the other way around) and so for all $P$ we must have $AP = PA$.

Comment: I guess to be completely rigorous you also have to consider the zero matrix right?

Comment: @nyquist_plot: By saying that $A = cI$ for some $c \in \mathbb{F}$ I included that option (as $c = 0$).

Comment: @levap absolutely, my bad!